# How can I add foreign language characters in #TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am developing a language app and my question is related to this. In this app, I can show the words from the local database that contain foreign characters in the app. Yet, when the users want to add a new word in a foreign language, the app does not recognize the foreign characters.

How can I make users add Turkish characters (or any other characters than English) in TextField in flutter? I am pretty new to developing apps. Any helpful answers would be really appreciated. I really thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to recognize for the language in **TextField**, Because the TextField can have any data in any **language**, You just have to change your own keyboard language to the language you want and you can start typing into that language like any other language.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest approach is the best! Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

To allow users to input Turkish characters or anyother character in Flutter, you will need to configure the TextField's inputFormatters property.

Use this code, it might help you:

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-ZığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ ]"))
  ],
)
```

It has the regex for Turkish and you can tweak this accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yet there is a new implementation as "FilteringTextInputFormatter" for "WhilelistingInputFormatter". Although I have tried your approach and several localization attempts which include other languages than English, the problem is solved when I upload the Turkish keyboard in the emulator.

I learned a lot about "inputFormatters" usage. Thanks again